# Inner div has borders - how to override with a class on an outer div?

Tags: css

Hey all - simple CSS newbie question, but I can't seem to enter the right question to ask my friend Google.

If an inner div has a class that adds borders, how can I put that div into an outer div and have that class override those borders?

The whole thing is a third party ListBox.  When it is created I am able to add a style (ClassToOverrideBorders) on the outer div in the code behind, but have no control over the inner div which adds borders.

```
<style>
.UserControlStyle .ClassWithBorders
{
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    background: #FFF;
}
</style>

<div class="UserControlStyle ClassToOverrideBorders">
    <div class="ClassWithBorders">
      <bunchofcontent />
    </div>
</div>
```

I suppose could use jQuery to do this (typed, not tested)...
`$('.UserControlStyle > * .ClassToOverrideBorders').removeClass('ClassWithBorders')`;

Thoughts?  Links to articles on how to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you edit the stylesheet? in your code if you set the `border` to `0px` it would remove it ..

Comment: I couldn't do that because then every instance of their control would not have the border.  It's only when I embed their control in another one that the borders are not appropriate.  For clarity, I didn't add too many pieces of info to my initial post...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the immediate child selector, and change the `border` property's value to `none`:

```
.UserControlStyle.ClassToOverrideBorders > .ClassWithBorders {
    border: none;
}
```

Using the 3 class names in this manner gives the rule higher specificity too.

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great, but I had to add the !important tag to it to get it to override the inner class.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Thad: you might want to rethink `!important` ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css/3706876#3706876)).  I've updated my answer to increase the specificity - perhaps that will work for you without requiring `!important`?

Comment: Done, done, and done!  Working perfectly and no need for !important.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You might try explicitly setting the style through the selectors:

```
.ClassToOverrideBorders .ClassWithBorders
{
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about specificity with the caveat that "!important" can take over occasionally.

If the 3rd party style is:

```
.ClassWithBorders
{
    border: 1px solid #8e8e8e;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

Then you can remove those borders with:

```
.UserControlStyle .ClassWithBorders
{
    border: 0;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

If, for some reason, this isn't working, try:

```
.UserControlStyle .ClassWithBorders
{
    border: 0 !important;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

If this is still not working, the 3rd party tool may be applying border styles via javascript, which you wouldn't be able to override via CSS (because of load & application order) and you'll need to go with a Javascript style change like:

```
$('.ClassWithBorder').css('border', 0);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using `!important` blindly - it would be better to try and get to the root of why something isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details on this, along with the jQuery example!  My initial jQuery statement would have removed ALL formatting applied by ClassWithBorders, which may not have been appropriate.

Comment: @Andy E - I totally agree. Unfortunately, CSS & Javascript are very reliant on the _whole_ DOM and we generally just get snippets here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ClassToOverrideBorders > div {
    border: none!important;
}
```

Comment: This would work, too, but I only wanted the outer border to not have borders.  Would this change ALL divs inside of the parent div, or just the immediate one because of the > ?

Comment: it overrides only immediate divs