# How edit <rich:fileUpload> CSS?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, upload, richfaces

I'm trying to show only the button `add` and the uploaded picture below the button, but it doesn't matter what I do in my CSS, the table generated by `richfaces` is always the same:

This is my form using `richfaces`:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" id="upload" acceptedTypes="jpg, gif, png, bmp"  ontyperejected="alert('Just JPG, GIF, PNG and BMP are allowed');" maxFilesQuantity="12" immediateUpload="true" >
                    <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="info" />
                </rich:fileUpload>

                <h:panelGroup id="info">
                    <h:outputText value="Add picture" rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size==0}" />
                    <rich:dataGrid columns="4" value="#{fileUploadBean.files}" var="file" rowKeyVar="row">
                        <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" mimeType="image/jpeg" createContent="#{fileUploadBean.paint}" value="#{row}" style="width:100px; height:100px;" cacheable="false" />
                    </rich:dataGrid>

                    <br />
                    <a4j:commandButton action="#{fileUploadBean.clearUploadData}" render="info, upload" value="Clear Uploaded Data" rendered="#{fileUploadBean.size>0}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

And this is how is generated :

[image: form]

I want something more simple 'cause in another moment I will some `jQuery slider` plugin. But I can't disappear with this table generated by `richfaces`.
And yes skins are [disable in my richfaces configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429254/richfaces-4-how-to-disable-skins):

**update**
Following the suggestion my CSS look like this now:

```
    <style>
    div div.rf-fu { border: 0px; width: 85px; }
    div div.rf-fu-hdr { border: 0px; }
    span span.rf-fu-btn-clr { border: 0px; }
    span.rf-fu-btns-lft{ width: 85px; }
    span.rf-fu-btns-rgh{ display: none; }
    div div.rf-fu-lst { display:none; }
    </style>
```

And now my `add..` file button looks like:

[image]

These post was very useful too:

[Should I use 'border: none' or 'border: 0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922909/should-i-use-border-none-or-border-0) 
[Inner div has borders - how to override with a class on an outer div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969977/inner-div-has-borders-how-to-override-with-a-class-on-an-outer-div)

Comment: Have you tried overriding richfaces css using the classes generated for richfaces elements ?

Comment: I tried but I was forgeting the `!important` attribute

Comment: Using `!important` is a bad practice and should always be considered a last resort ! Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Adrian's answer to override richfaces css however you don't need to use `!important` to override richfaces css. Just use [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) to override the css applied by richfaces.

For Instance in case where you are using `important`, apply the css as:

`div div.rf-fu-lst { display:none }` and it will work for you.

Comment: I have fixed my answer with your recommendations. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently doing this for my project. You have to override the richfaces css in your stylesheet like this:

```
.rf-fu, .rf-fu-hdr {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.rf-fu-btn-cnt-add {
    paddin-left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.rf-fu-btn-add {
    margin: 0;
}

.rf-fu-btns-rgh, .rf-fu-lst {
    display: none;
}

.rf-fu-btns-lft {
    width: 100%;
}
```